# Should I install Windows 7 on a 3 years old PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows

This is my PC configuration, Should I upgrade my Windows XP to Windows 7. Currently I'm using Windows XP SP3 32 bit. Now will I get same performance or better performance or bad performance if I install Windows 7 on this system?

Or would sticking with XP be better?

```
Memory (RAM):       1472 MB DDR RAM  (not DDR 2)
CPU Info:           AMD Sempron(tm) Processor 2500+
CPU Speed:          1398.7 MHz
Sound card:         Vinyl AC'97 Audio (WAVE)
Display Adapters:   VIA/S3G UniChrome Pro IGP | NetMeeting driver | RDPDD Chained DD
Network Adapters:   Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) | WAN (PPP/SLIP) Interface
Hard Disks:         300 GB SATA HDD
Manufacturer:       Phoenix Technologies, LTD
Product Make:       MS-7142
AC Power Status:    OnLine
BIOS Info:          AT/AT COMPATIBLE | 01/18/06 | VIAK8M - 42302e31
Motherboard:        MICRO-STAR INTERNATIONAL CO., LTD MS-7142
Modem:              ZTE USB Modem FFFE CDMA :
```

Comment: I would suggest checking the specs listed on the M$ website...

Answer (score 10):

Download this to check if it's fully compatible.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1B544E90-7659-4BD9-9E51-2497C146AF15&displaylang=en

> **Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor**
>
> *Brief Description*:
> Download and run the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor to see if your PC is ready for Windows 7. It scans your hardware, devices, and installed programs for known compatibility issues, gives you guidance on how to resolve potential issues found, and recommends what to do before you upgrade.

---

But yes, you should install it, I use it and it's better than every other OS I used.

Comment: Even if the processor is not the best one, I'd rather install Windows 7 instead of Vista! That's for sure!

Comment: my question is not "can i install", it's "should i install" or should stay with XP

Comment: Yhea yhea ok... same thing. My answer is YES! And also, check if it's fully compatible.

Comment: If he gets decent results from the upgrade advisor, he should definitely throw XP in the garbage can.  Otherwise, stick with XP until you get a newer machine.

Comment: if upgrade advisor passes all the things but still would it be a good decision to upgrade to Windows 7 with 1.5 GB DDR-I ram? Will i get any performance improvements.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, Windows 7. Besides the eye candy, it is more secure, arguably more stable, and has a longer support life going forward. Additionally, there are usability features that i think are big wins. All this can be argued, but Windows 7 is not a junky upgrade. I went from XP Pro to Windows 7. Never installed Vista, but i'm glad to have W7--just bought the final versions to replace the RC versions i had installed on two systems.

Your [**MS-7124/K8MM-V**](http://www.msicomputer.com/index.php?func=proddesc&maincat_no=1&prod_no=173) motherboard supports some upgrades. Maybe get a fresh [**2GB of RAM**](http://www.crucial.com/eu/store/listparts.aspx?model=MS-7142%20%28K8MM-V%29) for it and pick up an Athlon 64. Bumping the graphics card would help too. But these are relatively cheap upgrades.

*Case in point*: i had W7 on a four year old laptop (Dell 9300) with 1 GB RAM. It was usable but there was some HDD thrashing. Upgrading to 2 GB RAM ($64) made a huge difference. Much better than XP.

Comment: I don't play games on my PC should i buy Graphic card just for Windows 7 I just need Windows classic theme in windows 7 i don't need cool wallpaper and theme.

Comment: @Jitendra - no you don't **need** a fancy new Graphic Card for W7. The reason i suggested it is some of the UI improvements use any available GPU features. If you install W7 it will pick an appropriate UI feature set. From there it's easy to experiment with enabling/disabling features to see what you prefer. The most helpful upgrade for you will be 2 GB RAM or CPU, then video card. If your HDD is 5400 RPM, an upgrade to a 7200 RPM model will speed things up noticeably.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason that I would change an OS on a computer that was more than 2 years old is if it was due for a hard drive reformat, etc.  I don't think I'd do it for any other reason just in case you run into issues and the experiment becomes a 12 hour install/reinstall/marathon.

If you want a little extra security in the decision to upgrade or peace of mind, check out the [Microsoft Upgrade Adviser Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1B544E90-7659-4BD9-9E51-2497C146AF15&displaylang=en).

So to answer your question on should you upgrade, I think that it is a good idea, so long as you ***NEED*** to reformat your hard disk for any reason.

Answer (score 2):

This configuration should run Windows 7 just fine EXCEPT for the fact that your S3 graphics probably won't handle [Aero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero) very well.

I'd say upgrade to 4 GB of RAM and get a decent graphics card and you should be OK.  Also, there are probably lots of Athlon CPUs on [eBay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBay) that will fit that socket for DIRT CHEAP, so you can replace the [Sempron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sempron) as well.

Comment: My desktop is at least 5 years old.. but through the years it has had a new video card, new CPU, new motherboard, new RAM, new hard drives. It's like the old spade.. after 15 new handles and 8 new heads how old is it really?

Comment: if i don't need AERO then my system ok

Comment: @PP - Is that Trigg's moment from 'fools and horses ?  :))) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bk24RdfXWcg

Comment: FWIW, Windows 7 32-bit will only see 3GB of RAM (3.5GB on certain MB but that's more rare and depends on both the MB and any cards installed such as the Graphics card).  Upgrading to more than 3GB RAM on a 32-bit machine is a waste of $$$.